# Error in running Xcode program

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode5

When I compiled the existing code it was working fine, but when I create a new code and compile, it is showing following error:

`'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSString.h'
 has been modified since the precompiled header
 '/Users/arun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/3OQQ9G3BB8KEO/Foundation.pcm'`

Please help me fix this error.

Comment: Reinstall Xcode.  Something has messed with it (probably you).

Comment: go to this derive data directory and delete everything from it and try again..

Comment: no need to reinstall it look like you have changed the syntex of the in build framework

Comment: @Sunnyshah What we have to follow in this link? question is irrelevant to this question.

Comment: remove derivedata subfolder from xcode then run..

Comment: @Sunnyshah It doesn't make sense commenting as link, give some description. that's why asking.

Comment: how can i got to derived data

Comment: in your mac go to the folder /Users/Macmini17/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

Comment: ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData this command will work rite

Comment: You should delete ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache, clean the project and rebuild it

Answer (score 4):

Go to `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/` and delete all subfolder then Build the project

Answer (score 2):

Just select clean from the project menu. That should force a complete rebuild and solve the your problem.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

if by mistake you changed NSString.h file then there is no need to reinstall Xcode. just you need to copy and replace NSString.h file from another same xcode version which currently you used and clean your project and run the application it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced same issue in my project also. This issue arise Because you have visited `NSString.h`(Jump to definition or contrl+click on NSString property) and modified something in that file. Just visit again in NSString.h and `undo` what you have done.

**Note:** Try to close and reopen your project. seems to be funny but work sometime.

Answer (score 0):

I had also faced the same problem. I just clean the project and rebuild and it work. Hopefully it'll also worked for you.

Comment: I have reinstall the xcode itself but it causing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace NSString.h`file from another Xcode on path :`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSString.h`

This works for me! I hope it helps you.